# A question on a property of a nonnegative regular Borel measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading through a proof and ran across this statement, and I would just like clarification.

> Suppose $\mu$ is a nonnegative regular Borel measure on
>   $(\mathbf{R}^n)^m = \mathbf{R}^n \times \cdots \times \mathbf{R}^n$.
>   By translating $\mu$ if necessary, we may assume that there exists a
>   compact set $E\subset [1,M]^n \times \cdots \times [1,M]^n$ for some $M > 1$, such that $0 < \mu(E) < \infty$.

My question is, why is this true? And why is it possibly necessary to translate $\mu$? I know that for $\mu$ to be regular, then every Borel set $B$ is so that $$\mu(B) = \sup\{\mu(E) : E \subset B, E\mbox{ compact}\}$$ and since $I_M^n = [1,M]^n \times \cdots \times [1,M]^n$ is a Borel set,
$$\mu\big(I_M^n\big) = \sup\{\mu(E) : E \subset I_M^n, E\mbox{ compact}\}.$$ Thus, we can find a compact $E \subset I_M^n$ with $0 \leq \mu(E) \leq \mu\big(I_M^n\big)$, but why is this set so that $0 < \mu(E) < \infty$ and why can't we just take $E = I_M^n$ since $I_M^n$ is itself compact? Wouldn't we need to know $\mu\big(I_M^n\big)$ is so that $0 < \mu\big(I_M^n\big) < \infty$ anyway? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier than that. There exists a compact subset $E$ such that $0<\mu(E)<\infty$, for otherwise $\mu$ would be trivial. Being compact, $E$ is bounded, so it is contained in some box, say 
$$E\subset [-M, M]^n.$$
So if you translate both $\mu$ and $E$ you get a measure with the same  properties as $\mu$ and a compact subset $E'$ which is contained in $[1, 1+M\sqrt{n}]^n$.

Comment: Wow, that is easy and makes perfect sense. Thanks!